# Hack smartphone IC to draw more current and allow higher voltages?

Tags: battery-charging, charger, mobile

Disclaimer: This is just a laboratory experiment I am willing to do at my own risk. I understand the risk of blowing up the phone (GT-S5280) pr charger (Powstro 30W charger).
I already have a water bucket ready in the case of fire. Additionally, Iwear protectional gloves and protectional glasses.

Hello.

Sometimes, a smartphone fails to draw the available power of a power output, just because a high-resistance cable drops the voltage to 4.6V at the USB-B-Micro end, which is still 4.9V on the charger side. It only draws 0.3A out of a 5V×3A USB charger, despite even with resistance in the cable, there would be easily 1.5A available.

How can I manually enforce the smartphone charging controller to draw more current?

Comment: electricity and water .... i question your common sense .... you will need to contact the manufacturer for information about boosting the smartphone's charging controller

Comment: I think a bucket of sand is the preferred way to extinguish LiPo electrical fires...

Comment: i don't think you can: (Vin-Vbat) / Rwire... Vin doesn't change and Rwire doesn't change, so what can the regulator even do? it's not a boost+buck, so it can't draw the line down to 2v and still push 4.2v into the battery. what you can do is boost before the microUSB...

Comment: Again one of those questions where you **assume** something works in a certain way and that you can "hack" it to do what you want **instead** of investigating how it actually does work and learning from that.

Comment: Why don't you use a usb cable with a thicker wire with less resistance

Comment: @jsotola The icy cold water is for fire extinguishing. Better ruined electronics than fire.

Comment: @laptop2d It's just the phone refuses to draw more. The charger itself is designed to provide 4.9V, so the phone itself gets fooled into drawing less power.

Comment: @Jsotola The phone, not the charger would catch fire. The phone is the low voltage side.

Comment: If your providing adequate voltage to the phone, then you won't get the charging circuit to draw more current without modifying the charging controller circuit.

Comment: @Laptop2D So how can I modify it then?

Comment: Reverse engineer the circuit, open up your phone and hack a different circuit into the phone, you'll probably have wires sticking out of the phone with your end result. This is assuming that the battery isn't charging at the maximum rate, if it is then you'll also need to replace the battery

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do one thing for sure. Try a hacked cable that has bigger gauge wire so there is little or no voltage drop in the charger cable. Also make the cable shorter. Only thing this will achieve is to determine if a low terminal voltage at the phone is causing the phone to draw less current.

Other than that there is little that you can do to "force" the phone to take more current for charging. For most battery charging the current tapers off as the battery approaches the charged state.

Since most phones use totally custom batteries you would be running a risk to change its charging current even if it could be hacked.

Some phones may have a separate charge controller IC on the board which will control the battery charging current. But to be able to even determine if that can be hacked you would need to identify that part and find its data sheet. That could be getting on to a huge task if you do not have the schematic for the phone electronics.

Other phones are likely to have the battery charging controller built into the phone chip set. In this case the charging controller may very well be controlled by the phone firmware. It could be a challenge to figure out how to hack that even if you had the phone FW source code in hand - which I highly doubt.